# Changing cylindrical coordinates to cartesians's

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

I was wondering how to find $e_r$ using $e_x$ and $e_y$ as you can see in the scheme: [image]

So what I really want is to prove that:

> $$\vec{e_r}=\cos\theta\vec{e_x}+\sin\theta\vec{e_y}$$

with a deep proof using maths

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I already tried but they didn't give me any proof

Comment: @Qmechanic I agree, I think this may be off topic here.

Comment: Define "deep proof using maths." Seems to me it's straight-forward use of the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity)